# Sphinx FATAL: failed to parse config file

Tags: windows-services, sphinx

I am trying to start Sphinx as Windows:

```
searchd.exe --install --config c:\develop\sphinx\cs.config --servicename CSSearch
```

It has install correctly.

But, when I am trying to start service. I got Error 1067. In system log:

`FATAL: failed to parse config file 'c:\develop\sphinx\cs.config';`

When I am trying to execute searchd.exe:

```
searchd.exe --config c:\develop\sphinx\cs.conf
```

It's OK.

How can I start searchd as Win service correctly?

My cs.conf:

```
searchd
{
    listen      = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
    pid_file    = c:\Develop\sphinx\data\searchd.pid
    log     = c:\Develop\sphinx\log\sphinx.log
    #query_log  = c:\Develop\sphinx\log\query.log
    binlog_path = c:\Develop\sphinx\data\binlog\
    workers     = threads
    compat_sphinxql_magics = 0
    mysql_version_string = 5.5.21
    seamless_rotate = 0
}

index address
{
        type = rt
        dict = keywords
        path = c:\Develop\sphinx\data\index\address_index
        min_infix_len = 1
        enable_star = 1
        rt_field = country
        rt_field = region
        rt_field = city
        rt_field = street
}

index bank_detail
{
        type = rt
        dict = keywords
        path = c:\Develop\sphinx\data\index\bank_detail_index
        min_infix_len = 1
        enable_star = 1
        rt_field = bank_name
        rt_field = customer_name
        rt_field = settlement_account
}
```

Comment: Where is the source of the index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> --config c:\develop\sphinx\cs.config

and

> --config c:\develop\sphinx\cs.conf

They appear to be different filenames!